# Differential equations doubt

Tags: calculus

How can I solve this kind of differential equation?

$y' + 2xy^2 = 3x$

Note that it is not variables separable, and it can't be expressed in the first order linear differential equation form, in which we have $y'+u(t)y = f(t)$, where generally $u(t)$ is part of the method used to find the integrating factor.

Answer (score 3):

As I see the ODE, it can be written as follows: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x(3-2y^2)\to\frac{dy}{3-2y^2}-xdx=0, ~~3-2y^2\neq 0$$ which is separable. Note that $3-2y^2=0$ makes you the singular solutions.

Comment: Oh i see! Is it possible to solve it using FOLDE? Or it only works when we have the isolated $y$ term?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x(3-2y^2)$$
$$\frac{dy}{3-2y^2}=xdx$$ this is a seperable form